# visual studio code bash missing error trace

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

[image]

I'm using Julia on Visual Studio Code. I just found that the error trace is missing if I toggle bash up and down. If no toggle action is done, nothing went wrong, which is not possible for me.

Did anybody ever encounter this before? I'm sure it's a problem with Visual Studio Code because I tried toggle in another bash and the output is trimmed.

[image]

[image]

Taking this shell as example, a full output is what I need, but when I click 'toggle the panel' (marked red) to editor window and then return to shell, the full output is trimmed, like this. Most part will be lost, sometimes in the middle, sometimes at the beginning.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "*toggle bash up and down*"? Can you perhaps add screenshots of which parts of VS code are you talking about?

Comment: Doesn't the terminal scroll?

Comment: No, I can't scroll back.

Comment: The more times I toggle the panel, the less is showed in the terminal.